# Ruby 3.0.1, Rails 6 puma server connect not established

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, spring-boot

I've recently upgraded a rails app to ruby 3.0.1 and rails 6, I've installed Puma and set the default config, booting the server, however, I get the following.

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 6.1.3.2 application starting in development
=> Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Puma version: 5.3.2 (ruby 3.0.1-p64) ("Sweetnighter")
*  Min threads: 5
*  Max threads: 5
*  Environment: development
*          PID: 9665
* Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3000
* Listening on http://[::1]:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

[image]

This is the `puma.rb` config

```rb
# Puma can serve each request in a thread from an internal thread pool.
# The `threads` method setting takes two numbers a minimum and maximum.
# Any libraries that use thread pools should be configured to match
# the maximum value specified for Puma. Default is set to 5 threads for minimum
# and maximum, this matches the default thread size of Active Record.
#
threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 }.to_i
threads threads_count, threads_count

# Specifies the `port` that Puma will listen on to receive requests, default is 3000.
#
port        ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3000 }

# Specifies the `environment` that Puma will run in.
#
environment ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV") { "development" }

# Specifies the number of `workers` to boot in clustered mode.
# Workers are forked webserver processes. If using threads and workers together
# the concurrency of the application would be max `threads` * `workers`.
# Workers do not work on JRuby or Windows (both of which do not support
# processes).
#
# workers ENV.fetch("WEB_CONCURRENCY") { 2 }

# Use the `preload_app!` method when specifying a `workers` number.
# This directive tells Puma to first boot the application and load code
# before forking the application. This takes advantage of Copy On Write
# process behavior so workers use less memory. If you use this option
# you need to make sure to reconnect any threads in the `on_worker_boot`
# block.
#
# preload_app!

# The code in the `on_worker_boot` will be called if you are using
# clustered mode by specifying a number of `workers`. After each worker
# process is booted this block will be run, if you are using `preload_app!`
# option you will want to use this block to reconnect to any threads
# or connections that may have been created at application boot, Ruby
# cannot share connections between processes.
#
# on_worker_boot do
#   ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection if defined?(ActiveRecord)
# end

# Allow puma to be restarted by `rails restart` command.
plugin :tmp_restart
```

I've tailed the logs and I get the following

```
Being able to do this is deprecated. Autoloading during initialization is going
to be an error condition in future versions of Rails.

Reloading does not reboot the application, and therefore code executed during
initialization does not run again. So, if you reload Secretor, for example,
the expected changes won't be reflected in that stale Class object.

This autoloaded constant has been unloaded.

In order to autoload safely at boot time, please wrap your code in a reloader
callback this way:

    Rails.application.reloader.to_prepare do
      # Autoload classes and modules needed at boot time here.
    end

That block runs when the application boots, and every time there is a reload.
For historical reasons, it may run twice, so it has to be idempotent.

Check the "Autoloading and Reloading Constants" guide to learn more about how
Rails autoloads and reloads.
 (called from <main> at /home/ben/code/app/config/environment.rb:5)
```

This is my environment.rb

```rb
# Load the Rails application.
require_relative "application"

# Initialize the Rails application.
Rails.application.initialize!
```

Not sure what the issue is here, I'm using the default configs.

**EDIT**
application.rb

```rb
require_relative 'boot'

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)
require 'net/http'
require 'csv'

module RailsUpgrade
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Initialize configuration defaults for originally generated Rails version.
    config.load_defaults 6.1
    config.autoloader = :zeitwerk

    # Configuration for the application, engines, and railties goes here.
    #
    # These settings can be overridden in specific environments using the files
    # in config/environments, which are processed later.
    #
    # config.time_zone = "Central Time (US & Canada)"
    # config.eager_load_paths << Rails.root.join("extras")

    config.time_zone = 'London'

    config.log_level = :debug
    config.enable_dependency_loading = true
    config.eager_load_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')

    config.assets.enabled = true
    config.assets.version = '1.0'

    config.filter_parameters << :password
    config.filter_parameters << :password_confirmation
    config.filter_parameters << :card_number
    config.filter_parameters += [:password, :password_confirmation, :card_number]
  end
end
```

Comment: application.rb would be helpful too. There is this setting `config.load_defaults 6.1`, can you post it here?

Comment: Added at the bottom of the question @nuaky